# Listing files in a directory not matching pattern

Tags: python, glob

The following code lists down all the files in a directory beginning with `"hello"`:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob("hello*.txt")
```

How can I select other files that ARE NOT beginning with `"hello"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `glob` module's [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#module-glob), it works by using the [os.listdir()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) and [fnmatch.fnmatch()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html) functions in concert, and not by actually invoking a subshell.

`os.listdir()` returns you a list of entries in the specified directory, and `fnmatch.fnmatch()` provides you with unix shell-style wildcards, use it:

```
import fnmatch
import os

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if not fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'hello*.txt'):
        print file
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 8):

How about using glob only:

**Match all the files:**

```
>>> glob.glob('*')
['fee.py', 'foo.py', 'hello.txt', 'hello1.txt', 'test.txt', 'text.txt']
>>>
```

**Match only `hello.txt`:**

```
>>> glob.glob('hello*.txt')
['hello.txt', 'hello1.txt']
>>>
```

**Match without string `hello`:**

```
>>> glob.glob('[!hello]*')
['fee.py', 'foo.py', 'test.txt', 'text.txt']
>>>
```

**Match without string `hello` but ending with `.txt`:**

```
>>> glob.glob('[!hello]*.txt')
['test.txt', 'text.txt']
>>>
```

Comment: `glob('[!hello]*')` would discard much more than just names beginning with `"hello"`.  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/fnmatch.html): `[!seq]` matches any character not in `seq`

Answer (score 0):

You could simply match *all* files using the `"*"` pattern, then weed out the ones you're not interested in, e.g.:

```
from glob import glob
from fnmatch import fnmatch

files = [f for f in glob("*") if not fnmatch(f, "hello*.txt")]
```