# Move files with only ".hex" extensions in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, move, shutil

I want to move files with only ".hex" extensions in source path. I wrote the codes like below;

```
os.makedirs(dst)
src = "C:\\source_path"
dst = "C:\\destination_path"

for filename in os.listdir():
    if filename.endswith('.hex'):
        shutil.move(src, dst , copy_function = copy2)
```

The file was created but empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [listing files from a directory using glob python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625616/listing-files-from-a-directory-using-glob-python)

Comment: why using `copy_function = copy2` ??
try using 
`os.rename(src, dst)`
`shutil.move(src, dst)`

Comment: You need to specify the file path not just the dir names.

Comment: Even if I write `shutil.move(src, dst)`, there is no change in destination file. I just try  `copy_function = copy2`

Comment: Files are constantly being updated. There is no fixed file name. That's why I try to move file endswith '.hex'

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to move the file, not the folder. (use `os.path.join(src,filename)`)
2. you are not going over the `src` dir. (use `os.listdir(src)`)

Try something like this:

```
os.makedirs(dst)
src = "C:\\source_path"
dst = "C:\\destination_path"

for filename in os.listdir(src):
    if filename.endswith('.hex'):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(src,filename), dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
src = "C:\\source_path"
dst = "C:\\destination_path"
os.makedirs(dst, exist_ok=True)
```

**First Way;**

```
source = os.listdir(src)
for files in source:
    if files.endswith(".hex"):
        if not files.endswith("sample.hex"):
            shutil.move(files,dst)
```

**Second Way;**

```
source = os.listdir(src)
for files in source:
    if files.endswith(".hex"):
        if not files.endswith("sample.hex"):
            shutil.move(os.path.join(src, files), os.path.join(dst, files))
```